# .gitignore setup for directories

Tags: git, gitignore

I`ve the following directory structure and i want to add the directories "public" and "brand" to git, but no other subdirectories of /app/:

```
/app
--.gitignore
--/public
----.gitkeep
----/brand
------.gitkeep
```

The /app/.gitignore file looks as follows:

```
*
!public/.gitkeep
!public/brand/.gitkeep
!.gitignore
```

However, only the "public" directory is added to git but not the .gitkeep files nor the directory "brand". Do you have an idea what´s wrong with the .gitignore file?

Comment: If you don't include the `.gitkeep` files how will git know to keep the directory in the repo? Either way: you will have to add and commit the `.gitignore` to your repo first. Have you done that?

Comment: AFAIK, Git doesn't store folders, instead it stores files and their paths.

Comment: Due to the `*`, your `/public` directory gets ignored, and once a directory is ignored, it's impossible to include any of its files even with the `!` statements.
Quote from https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format : «It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.»

Comment: I personally dislike the `.gitkeep` file trick. We know (from the fact that Git stores only files and submodules, not folders; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452) for details, including a submodule trick you can use if you want) that we want to put a file into the directory just for Git purposes. We also know that we want Git to exclude all *other* files in this directory. So why not put in a `.gitignore` file that has two lines, `*` and `!/.gitignore`? It's simple and explicit: we put *exactly this file* in every directory we want to store as an empty directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs! Here´s the solution that works for me now:

```
*
!public/
!public/**/
!public/**/.gitkeep
```